error while applying kubernetes from yml file
kubectl apply -f k8s/deployment.yml --validate=false

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: <user arn> is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: <cluster role arn>
E1111 21:37:30.036257   14704 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://5E52EE866A68FF445D9EFF54FF06C3FF.gr7.ap-south-1.eks.amazonaws.com/api?timeout=32s": getting credentials: exec: executable aws failed with exit code 254
error: unable to recognize "k8s/deployment.yml": Get "https://5E52EE866A68FF445D9EFF54FF06C3FF.gr7.ap-south-1.eks.amazonaws.com/api?timeout=32s": getting credentials: exec: executable aws failed with exit code 254


kubectl apply -f k8s/clusterrolebinding.yml --validate=false

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: <<user arn>> is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: <<cluster role arn>>
E1112 12:33:01.210734   35556 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://5E52EE866A68FF445D9EFF54FF06C3FF.gr7.ap-south-1.eks.amazonaws.com/api?timeout=32s": getting credentials: exec: executable aws failed with exit code 254
error: unable to recognize "k8s/clusterrolebinding.yml": Get "https://5E52EE866A68FF445D9EFF54FF06C3FF.gr7.ap-south-1.eks.amazonaws.com/api?timeout=32s": getting credentials: exec: executable aws failed with exit code 254 

I tried creating default, role and cluster role binding ,even those are givin the same errors.

You are using the cluster role to create K8S resources. That role is for the cluster as a resource to operate in AWS. Use this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/access-entries.html to provide access for your user/role

This worked by adding an access entry point to my cluster
where ?
eks > clusters >  Access > IAM Access entries > Create an access entry.


You are trying to leverage a cluster role and you get this error.
I'm guessing you only have a namespace role. See here, you can grant cluster role by following the documentation.
